# Finding $\int_0^1 (1+e^{-x^2})dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find $\int_0^1
(1+e^{-x^2})dx$ 
(a) $~-1$
(b) $~2$

(c) $~1+e^{-1}$
 (d) None of above
My attempt: 
Using bounds of given continuous function: 
$\begin{aligned}\forall x\in(0,1)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~-x<-x^2<0&\implies 1+e^{-x}<1+e^{-x^2}<2\\&\implies\int_0^11+e^{-x}~dx<\int_0^11+e^{-x^2}~dx<\int_0^12~dx\\&\therefore, 2-\frac{1}{e} <\int_0^11+e^{-x^2}~dx<2
\end{aligned}$
which is enough to conclude that option (d) is correct.
 This is also the standard solution provided by all books.

I wanted to know if there is any way to calculate the exact value of the integral without using bounds. 
I tried using substitutions but to no avail. 
Edit: I haven't learned contour integration yet so I prefer solutions using Real analysis if possible.

Comment: You need a special function called the error function, which is widely available in software.

Comment: The exact value of the integral is involves the Error function, $1+\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}Erf(1)$.

Comment: Is there any way to solve using real analysis.?

Comment: No; erf is not an elementary function, and there is no way to represent this that isn't equivalent to using it.

Comment: You won’t find a closed for for this, but you can definitely eliminate some of the answers…

Comment: Just a small remark: $\displaystyle {\rm erf}(z):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-t^{2}}\, {\rm d}t$, where ${\rm erf}$ is the error function and it is non elementary function.

Comment: Both contour integration and "Real Analysis" using Polar substitution gives closed form for the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$ or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$ . You cannot find the closed form for this definite integral. You can at best approximate it.

Comment: I agree then. Can we make instead a better approximation than mine (1.63, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering a comment by the OP :

You can improve the upper bound for example by finding the tangent of $f(x)=-x^2$ with slope $-1$.  Then $f'(x_0) = -2x_0 =-1$ , so it is the tangent at $x_0 = \frac{1}{2}$ , its function is $y + \frac{1}{4} = -(x-\frac{1}{2}) $ which gives you $y = -x + \frac{1}{4}$ which  means that $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} < \int_0^1 e^{-x+\frac{1}{4}}= 0.811659... $;

You can also use a taylor approximation to find better estimates indeed the function $e^{-x^2}$ is bounded below by a taylor approximation with an even number of terms and above by a taylor approximation with an odd number of terms

$$ 1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}-...+(-1)^{2k+1}\frac{x^{2(2k+1)}}{(2k+1)!}< e^{-x^2} < 1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}-...+ (-1)^{2k} \frac{x^{2(2k)}}{(2k)!} $$

Comment: Your approximation looks much better than mine. I reposted the comment now.